# How can I get accurate latitude/longitude of current GPS location?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, geolocation, android-gps

I am using `GPS Tracker` class and I want to get an accurate current location.

But every time, I am getting a different location (20-meter accuracy).

GPS Tracker Class: http://eclatsol.net/GPSTracker.java

Code :

```
gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
if (gpsTracker.canGetLocation()) {
   mLatitude = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
   mLongitude = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
}
```

at that time I am doing `Indoors` testing.

Comment: Which gps tracker class?

Comment: Turn on High accuracy location services

Comment: @TimCastelijns i did high accuracy location services. and i found that bug in Ola application also

Comment: Sorry but can you elaborate where that tracker class comes from? Which import?  Never seen before.

Comment: then this is the best you're gonna get

Comment: @greenapps i am using LocationListener

Comment: import android.location.Geocoder;

import android.location.Location;

import android.location.LocationListener;

import android.location.LocationManager;

that are my imports

Comment: You wrote a bad post. You are not giving any info about your use case. Indoors? Outdoors? In the woods? Moving? You complain about software but most probably you have to complain about the quality of the gps chip in your Android device. Or about the impossibility of a gps chip to calculate the position when static.

Comment: _"I am using GPS Tracker class"_ Then that's probably the root cause of your problems. _"And i am using LocationListener"_ But are you using it properly? We can't know that without any code. _"at that time i am doing Indoors testing"_ GPS doesn't really work indoors.

Comment: @greenapps please open http://eclatsol.net/GPSTracker.java , i am using that class for tracking gps

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen please see that class eclatsol.net/GPSTracker.java

Comment: The problems of the infamous "GPS tracker" code is explained in detail [in this blog post by Gabe Sechan](http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/). It continuously keeps causing headache for developers that look for an "easy solution" and end up using bad example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refer [Fused Location API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) and it's high accuracy option. The documentation [says](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html),

> PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY - Use this setting to request the most precise location possible. With this setting, the location services are more likely to use GPS to determine the location.

Now i'v also tested (indoor, near balcony) on old device (Samsung Galaxy S3). I'm receiving location updates between 5m and 15m accuracy. The tested code from, [googlesamples/android-play-location](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationUpdates/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdates/MainActivity.java)

Answer (score 0):

GPSTrackerclass
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 5;

Comment: i did that but its not accurate